# Integral of multiplication of two $\iint Q(f(r,\theta ))Q(h(r,\theta )) \,dr\,d\theta $ function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have an integral,

\begin{align}
y & = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} Q\left( - (r\cos \theta  + b)a \right) Q\left( { - (r\sin \theta  + c)d} \right)f\left( {r,\theta } \right) \, dr \, d\theta \\[6pt]
& = \int_0^\infty g(r)f(r)\,dr
\end{align}

where, $z = r{e^{j\theta }};z \in C$ and $a,b,c,d \in R$.

I wanted to find ${g(r )}$.

1. Is there any way I can find that?
2. Is there any theorem that might help me find that?

Comment: In the first expression, $f$ is a function of two variables. In the second one, it's a function of one variable. Are those two different functions?

Comment: I think you are right. How should I solve that?